# XCode Swift 2 UITableViewCell dynamic height based on distance to center

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Im trying to create a custom date day picker from a `TableView` where the numbers get larger as they get toward the center of the screen. For example in the following image: [Date Picker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aIic.png)

I'm storing the cell heights and calling the following code in `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, and of course the height changes only take place after the scroll has happened, but how could I dynamically change the cell heights as it moves?

```
let pathForCenterCell = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.tableView.bounds)))

self.cellHeights[pathForCenterCell!.row - 2] = 88
self.cellHeights[pathForCenterCell!.row - 1] = 120
self.cellHeights[pathForCenterCell!.row] = 160
self.cellHeights[pathForCenterCell!.row + 1] = 120
self.cellHeights[pathForCenterCell!.row + 2] = 88
```

And how should I setup constraints so that the boxes in the cells and numbers grow along with the cell height and maintain the same space between them horizontally (see the above image)

Comment: The cell height of the tableview is fetched from the delegate when you reload the tableview. But I think that the performane would not be good enough. I would do my own component without a tableview, it doesn't seem to complicated.

Comment: It seems that performance is ok if I change my height values inside scrollViewDidScroll and then call beginUpdates, endUpdates on the tableview. Any ideas how I can actually tween these values to create the desired effect as the user scrolls? And how to constrain the boxes correctly?